# Where are the Kerberos time outs in Windows 2008R2?

Tags: kerberos, dfs, cifs, emc

We have a DFS share that redirects users to a EMC CIFS share.  Several end users are unable to access it and get the following Kerberos Security warning:

> The System Detected an attempt to compromise security

I believe it's because the Kerberos permitted clock skew on the DC's is set too low.

Where do I set this, or what other items may be the culprit?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Also you want to fix timesync, not mess with the allowed clock skew settings

Comment: @Zypher I'll update the error message shortly.  The time is within .06 seconds of the DC.  I suspect a previous admin decreased this value to "increase" security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shane is right about the time skew, it is probably not your issue; the default setting is 5 minutes tolerance btw.

When talking about time-outs, be aware that the time-out value for a Kerberos v5 authentication operation is 30 seconds. This can be adjusted by the `KdcWaitTime` value in the following key on the Domain Controller:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters]
```

Another issue (although uncommon in small and mid-sized forests), is the default token size limitation of 12 kilobytes. If the users token size exceeds 12K, you might also run into problems. Read more about the [token size issue here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/surama/archive/2009/04/06/kerberos-authentication-problem-with-active-directory.aspx)

This is guesswork however, as your question doesn't really bring any valuable diagnostic information to the table

Comment: What diagnostics should I collect?

Comment: The details that lead you to believe the time skew has anything to do with this, and the exact warnings/errors that users receive

Answer (score 3):

If the time's within a second, then clock skew is not your issue.  The most sensitive that it can be configured to is 1 minute.

That said, the setting is located within Computer Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Account Policies -> Kerberos Policy, "Maximum tolerance for computer clock synchronization".